# Generating Non-Stationary Time Series in R

Tags: r, time-series, autoregressive-models

I wish to generate an AR(3) model with parameters (3,0,5) for each of the phi's.
This is non-stationary and arima.sim gives the error

```
Error in arima.sim(model = list(ar = c(3, 0, 5)), n = 50) :'ar' part of 
model is not stationary
```

Is there a way this can be done in R?

Comment: Take a look at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127441/initialize-arp-process-by-using-arima-sim.

Comment: provide a reproducible example

Answer (score 3):

What process variance (SD) did you want to use? If unspecified, `arima.sim()` will use a default of 1 so I'll assume that's also the case you want here.

```
# empty vector for process
xx <- vector("numeric",50)
# innovations (process errors)
ww <- rnorm(50)
# set first 3 times to innovations
xx[1:3] <- ww[1:3]
# simulate AR(3)
for(t in 4:50) { xx[t] <- 3*xx[t-1] + 5*xx[t-3] + ww[t] }
```

If you don't want Gaussian errors, replace `ww` with some other distribution.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I used, just forgot to update the answer here!